# How can I make code in Django only run when debug is set to true

Tags: python, django

I have some code that should only be run for testing purposes on the local computer.
I guess the most simple way is to check if debug is set to true.

How would I be able to check if this is the case.
The version of Django is 1.4.5

Ofcourse if there is a better way to only run code when I am on a local workstation I would appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you write a test itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`django.conf.settings.DEBUG`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEBUG) ([Django 1.4 documentation link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEBUG)):

```
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
    # Codes that will run only in DEBUG mode
```